# sqlLinq Take higher RN number

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Here is My Query

```
var sonuc = (from c in cd.Product
                        join pp in cd.Product_Picture_Mapping
                            on c.ID equals pp.ProductID
                        join pcc in cd.Picture
                            on pp.PictureID equals pcc.ID
                         select new ProductViewModel() { PicturePath = pcc.Path, ProductID = c.ID }).OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).ToList().AsEnumerable().Select((entry, index) => new ProductViewModel()
                         {
                             PicturePath = entry.PicturePath,
                             ProductID = entry.ProductID
                         }).OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).GroupBy(x => x.ProductID).Select(g => new { g, count = g.Count() })
            .SelectMany(t => t.g.Select(b => b).Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, t.count), (j, i) => new { j.ProductID, j.PicturePath, rn = i }));
```

and OUTPUT;

```
PicturePath   ProductID RN
samplepath1    4         1
samplepath2    5         1
samplepath3    10        1
samplepath4    10        2
samplepath5    10        3
```

so, i want to take one row that have same Product id by higher RN, like this.

```
PicturePath   ProductID RN
samplepath1    4         1
samplepath2    5         1
samplepath5    10        3
```

How can i get like this ?
Thank you

Comment: Side note - instead of `t.g.Select(b => b).Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, t.count), (j, i) => new { j.ProductID, j.PicturePath, rn = i })` you can use overloaded Select operator `t.g.Select((j, rn) => new { j.ProductID, j.PicturePath, rn })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by ProductID and select item with max RN from each group:

```
var result = from x in sonuc
             group x by x.ProductID into g
             select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.RN).First();
```

Comment: thank you, just i want to ask one question how can i add this result to my ProductViewModel ?
i mean select new ProductViewModel ()

Comment: @DursunICCAN your can project this anonymous type to ProductViewModel - it has properties for ProductID and PicturePath